# Is there a migration required when adding a new realm object in realm-swift?

Tags: swift3, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-migration

Does realm need migration when adding a new object in **realm-swift**?

I already have an object in Realm. Now, I want to add to new Realm object. 

Do I need to add migration for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You only need to perform a migration when you change an existing model/class in your Realm schema.

A migration is only needed, when you are changing properties of existing objects. If you are adding a new Object model/new Object or just changing values of existing models, you don't need a migration.

Comment: @Anmol you asked about `realm-swift` and you added the `swift3` tag, so why would I answer about Android?

Comment: I was just saying. Since you didn't mention in your answer that you're talking just about `realm-swift`.

Comment: Well, since the question was clearly about `realm-swift`, why would I have to mention that I am only talking about this specific framework?

Comment: Sure David. I agree with you.